# mouse lag while downloading files

Tags: 18.04

I have no idea why this issue happen.
I just guess graphics card may cause this problem, but I am not sure.
my computer(`Acer aspire V 13`) spec. and ubuntu version as below:

```
----ubuntu version----
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

----computer spec.----
graphics card:
                       Intel HD Graphics 520
sound:
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
storage:
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
network:
  wlp3s0               Qualcomm Atheros QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
  enp2s0               Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
network interface:
  enp2s0               Ethernet network interface
  lo                   Loopback network interface
  wlp3s0               Ethernet network interface
disk:
  /dev/sda             SAMSUNG MZNLN256
partition:
  /dev/sda1            Partition
usb controller:
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
bios:
                       BIOS
bridge:
                       Intel PCI bridge
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP LPC Controller
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #6
                       Intel Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
                       Intel Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #5
hub:
                       Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
                       Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
```

Does anyone have same problem and fixed it?

Comment: What filesystem are you downloading to? There is a long-standing issue with NTFS writes taking a lot of CPU resources. Try monitoring the system while downloading, is the RAM/Swap or CPU usage high?

Comment: @int_ua I see, but I couldn't catch any issue in RAM/Swap/CPU usage while downloading files about30MB(but there was still mouse lag issue) . Would you teach me how to test it?